# how to clear stuff from "game" screen in "gameover" screen?

Tags: actionscript

I got my game to work after adding few things like subtracting scores, and adding another frame so that when I fail to catch an object five times, I'll go to "GameOver" screen. However, I'm unable to clear the stuff from the "Game" screen in "GameOver" screen. How do I do it? I got my source code from: http://flashgameu.com/Catching_Game_Part_2_id20090312-131621.html.

Anyway, here are my actionscript 3.0 code:

package {
    import com.greensock.*;

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;

public class CatchingSkittles extends MovieClip {
    var girlmouth:GirlMouth;
    var girlmouthfront:GirlMouthFront;
    var nextObject:Timer;
    var objects:Array = new Array();
    var score:int = 0;
    var missedItems:int = 0;
    var speed:Number = 7.0;

    public function CatchingSkittles() {
        girlmouthfront = new GirlMouthFront();
        girlmouthfront.y = -49.00;
        girlmouth = new GirlMouth();
        girlmouth.y = 308.55;
        addChild(girlmouth);
        girlmouth.addChild(girlmouthfront);
        setNextObject();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObjects);
    }

    public function setNextObject() {
        nextObject = new Timer(1000+Math.random()*1000,1);
        nextObject.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,newObject);
        nextObject.start();
    }

    public function newObject(e:Event) {
        var goodObjects:Array = ["Red","Purple","Yellow","Orange","Green"];

        if (Math.random() < .8) {
            var r:int = Math.floor(Math.random()*goodObjects.length);
            var classRef:Class = getDefinitionByName(goodObjects[r]) as Class;
            var newObject:MovieClip = new classRef(); 
            newObject.typestr = "good";
        } else {
            r = Math.floor(Math.random()*goodObjects.length);
            classRef = getDefinitionByName(goodObjects[r]) as Class;
            newObject = new classRef(); 
            newObject.typestr = "good";
        }
        newObject.x = Math.random()*510;
        addChild(newObject);
        objects.push(newObject);
        setNextObject();
    }

    public function moveObjects(e:Event) {
        for(var i:int=objects.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            objects[i].y += speed;
            if (objects[i].y > 425) {
                score -= 5;
                removeChild(objects[i]);
                objects.splice(i,1);
                missedItems +=1;
                if (missedItems == 5) {
                gotoAndStop(2);
                finalScoreDisplay.text = "Score: "+score;
                }
            }
            if (objects[i].hitTestObject(girlmouthfront)) {
                if (objects[i].typestr == "good") {
                    score += 5;
                } else {
                    score += 5;
                }

                removeChild(objects[i]);
                objects.splice(i,1);
            }
            scoreDisplay.text = "Score: "+score;


        }

        girlmouth.x = mouseX;
    }


}
```

}

I've been trying to edit everything in function moveObjects() under "missedItems", but I just can't make it work....

Answer (score 0):

What is still on the screen, and what do you want removed?

It looks like the **girlmouth** symbol is the main symbol you want to remove. If that's the case, try this:

```
if (missedItems == 5) {
    removeChild(girlmouth);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObjects);
    gotoAndStop(2);
    finalScoreDisplay.text = "Score: "+score;
}
```